# How to read JSON data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, coldfusion

This might be a silly question, but I really hope someone can help me here.

I'm currently using `serializeJson()`, within ColdFusion 10, to generate a JSON dataset so I can process the data within a jquery table plugin. serializeJson() generates the following JSON data:

```
{
-COLUMNS: [
"AMOUNT"
"AMOUNTPAID"
"ENTITY"
"ENTITY_NAME"
"FORMULACURRENCY"
"INTERNALID"
"TRANDATE"
"TRANID"
"TYPE"
"TYPE_INTERNALID"
]
-DATA: [
...
```

My plugin only seems to only handle very basic JSON.

```
[{"rank":1,"title":"The Avengers (2012)","weekend":"$103M","gross":"$373M","weeks":2},
            {"rank":2,"title":"Dark Shadows (2012)","weekend":"$29.7M","gross":"$29.7M","weeks":1},
            {"rank":3,"title":"Think Like a Man (2012)","weekend":"$5.82M","gross":"$81.4M","weeks":4},
            {"rank":4,"title":"The Hunger Games (2012)","weekend":"$4.51M","gross":"$387M","weeks":8},
            {"rank":5,"title":"The Lucky One (2012)","weekend":"$4.11M","gross":"$53.8M","weeks":4},
            {"rank":6,"title":"The Five-Year Engagement (2012)","weekend":"$3.31M","gross":"$24.6M","weeks":3},
            {"rank":7,"title":"The Pirates! Band of Misfits (2012)","weekend":"$3.14M","gross":"$23M","weeks":3},
            {"rank":8,"title":"The Best Exotic Marigold Hotel (2011)","weekend":"$2.67M","gross":"$3.74M","weeks":2},
            {"rank":9,"title":"Chimpanzee (2012)","weekend":"$1.76M","gross":"$25.7M","weeks":4},
            {"rank":10,"title":"Safe (2012)","weekend":"$1.45M","gross":"$15.7M","weeks":3}];
```

How does one only get an array of the data, not the columnlist or any other meta data, from ColdFusion's serializeJson() function? Or alternatively is there an easy way to fetch content only from within the data array, without the other arrays?

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a bit vague, but I'll try to answer it.

`serializeJson()` and `deserializeJson()` only do precisely what they say on the tin: converts native CFML data structures to/from a JSON-formatted string. They don't in and of themselves dictate the structure of the translation.

Your jQuery plug-in expects an array of JavaScript objects, which means you need to create and array of JavaScript objects. One nod here to how data is translated between a CFML type and a JSONified JS type is that a CFML struct will serialise as a JS object.

So if you are starting with a CFML recordset... you need to think about how to use that to create an array of structures. I suggest you have a structure for each row, and each of those rows is an element in the array.

So you'll want something like this:

```
create an array
loop over the recordset
    create a struct out of each column value of the current row
    append that struct to the array
/loop
serialise the array to JSON
```

There is no one-off / built-in functionality which converts a recordset object to an array of structs. You need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting `serializeQueryByColumns` to `true`?  See if you like that style better.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79fa.html

Answer (score 2):

I built [ArrayCollection.cfc](https://github.com/iknowkungfoo/ArrayCollection) for just this reason. I needed to easily convert a ColdFusion query into a more standard JSON format. There's a [blog post](http://iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/5/11/ArrayCollectioncfc-a-custom-JSON-renderer-for-ColdFusion-queries) that covers the use cases.

It creates an array of structs or an array of arrays based on the contents of the query object, then serializes it.

```
<cfset rs.ac = createObject("component", "ArrayCollection").init() />
<cfset rs.ac.setData( myQuery ) />
<cfreturn rs.ac.$renderdata() />
```

This outputs this default JSON format:

```
{    
    "data":[
        {
            "bookid":8,
            "genre":"Fiction",
            "title":"Apparition Man"
        },
        {
            "bookid":2,
            "genre":"Non-fiction",
            "title":"Shopping Mart Mania"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can turn the "data" key off or change its value as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
<cfset tempList = "AMOUNT,AMOUNTPAID,ENTITY,ENTITY_NAME,FORMULACURRENCY,INTERNALID">

<cfsavecontent variable="tempJSON"> [
<cfloop query="#yourQry#">
    <cfset counterTwo=0>
    {
    <cfloop list="#tempList#" index="columnname">
        <cfset counterTwo=counterTwo+1>
        #columnname#:
        <cfif IsNumeric(serializeJson(trim(Evaluate('#columnname#'))))>
        "#trim(Evaluate('yourQry.#columnname#'))#"
        <cfelse>
        #serializeJson(trim(Evaluate('yourQry.#columnname#')))#
        </cfif>

    <cfif counterTwo IS NOT ListLen(tempList))>
       ,
    </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    }
    <cfif currentrow IS NOT recordcount>
      ,
    </cfif>
</cfloop> ]
</cfsavecontent>
```

So just replace my query with your array, I was looping over columns because I had dynamic columns, so they were user specific. If your JSON has fixed number of keys then you wouldn't have to loop through the list, you can just specify it manually.

Like this you create your JSON and pass it to the jQuery table plugin.

Comment: wouldn't this introduce a lot of whitespaces?  I'm not sure if the `tempJSON` will be a valid JSON string.

Comment: It will not introduce whitespaces, and it will be a valid JSON string. I am using jqGrid to display my table and I just return this JSON and use <cfoutput>#returnedJSON#</cfoutput> in the data field. Works perfectly. I am using it everywhere in my app. Give it a try.

Comment: Nice, great, I guess I had history with `cfsavecontent`.

Comment: There is another option too, you can use jQuery to create this JSON for you, but that would be a huge response if you're returning this query on a different page. So you can just use JavaScript to loop through and create JSON the same way we did it in Coldfusion.

Comment: No need to roll your own JSON. Just create an array, append some structures, then serialize the array at the end. (see [Adam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21842349/104223)). Also, `evaluate`'s is discouraged. For dynamic column names, just use associative array notation: `queryName["columnName"][rowNumber]`

Comment: I agree with using associative array notation. My query returned about 100,000 results so I thought creating an array of structures would use a lot of memory and creating JSON instead of creating structures would be lightweight. So it was faster too. Just my opinion.

Comment: That is a pretty big query... what is the consumer of the JSON? Definitely not jquery ...

Comment: It's jQuery. I needed to show results of that query in jqGrid jQuery grid plugin. It was a parametric report and it joined like 25 different columns. So I guess that was the best way for me.

Comment: Returning a 100K rows of data to jquery? That is insane.

Comment: That's why I created JSON and returned JSON to jQuery grid plugin. How else would I be able to show in a grid?

Comment: Paginate on the server side, so you only return a batch of `N` records at a time, not all 100K. Users can still scroll through all 100K records if they *really* wanted to (which I cannot imagine) but the server only sends back one page of records at a time.

Comment: I have done pagination at few places, but in this case I had to use datatype local because in this grid we were not providing any option to search, so once I load all 100K records use can sort easily through that instead of sending an AJAX request every time and waiting for the query to finish executing which was taking at least 10 seconds to execute even for 10 records. So I thought let the user wait once and in about 30 seconds they'll have the whole data to see and sort.

Comment: If basic queries are taking too long, you need to look into tuning your indexes. Bringing 100K rows down the wire for each user really is not a good solution. It requires a huge amount of resources, on the CF server, network and client - and it is not scalable. `</hijack>`

Comment: It actually wasn't a basic query. It joined about 25 columns and all of them had indexes. So it was taking a little bit to load. This was very rare situation though, it will return 100K only if user tries to do a blank search on our database records. So when user will give some search criteria it should return around 10K - 20K results, which is still not feasible if I want to use array of structures.

Comment: My point is you should be tuning the database side of things, rather than trying to work around the problem by pulling back tens of thousands of records to a browser ;-) No matter how you slice that it is not going to be very efficient. That said, we have probably hijacked the OP's thread long enough. [Stack Overflow is different than a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), this kind of extended discussion is discouraged in the Q&A area. It really belongs in chat, but unfortunately that requires a [little more reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on client side also easily.

```
$.standardiseCfQueryJSON=function( cfQueryJSON )
{
 var result  =   [];
 $.each( cfQueryJSON.DATA,function( rowNum,rowValue ){
     var row =   new Object();
     $.each( cfQueryJSON.COLUMNS,function( position,columnName ){
        row[ columnName.toLowerCase() ] = rowValue[ position ];
     });
    result.push( row );
    });
    return result;
};
```

And in the AJAX call just convert the data to a valid JSON format and use it,

```
 success: function(response){
   data = $.standardiseCfQueryJSON(response);
 }
```